# Android Input Methods

Tags: android-softkeyboard, tamil

We are creating an app for tamil keyboard in that we are providing suggestions like a,an,and, etc.. while clicking that suggestion it is not displayed in default editText field of our mobile phone. so, My query is how to display suggestion to the default textbox while clicking the particular suggestion.